# Alguna duda relacionada con sentencias SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Tengo una pregunta con referente sql

Tengo una tabla llamada 'cuota' el cual almacena una fecha y un monto (ademas de su id) y ademas tengo otra tabla llamada 'propietario'. Lo que quiero saber es si puedo hacer una sola sentencia en sql que me haga insertar todas las id de los registros de la tabla 'propietario' mas las id de uno de los registros de la tabla 'cuota' a una tercera tabla llamada 'propietarioDebeCuota'.

aqui estan las tablas que estoy usando (estoy usando MySQL)

```
CREATE TABLE propietario(
    idPropietario int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    cedulaProp int(8) NOT NULL,
    idAptto int(8) NOT NULL,
    fechaAdquisicion date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idPropietario),
    FOREIGN KEY (cedulaProp) REFERENCES persona(cedula),
    FOREIGN KEY (idAptto) REFERENCES apartamento(idApartamento)
);

CREATE TABLE cuota(
    idCuota int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fechaC date DEFAULT NULL,
    monto integer NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idCuota)
);

CREATE TABLE propietarioDebeCuota(
    idDeuda int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    idPropietario int(10) NOT NULL,
    idCuotaDeudora int(8) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (idDeuda),
    FOREIGN KEY (idPropietario) REFERENCES propietario(cedulaProp),
    FOREIGN KEY (idCoutaDeudora) REFERENCES cuota(idCuota)
);
```

Me doy cuenta que lo que trato de hacer no se puede sino desde el codigo php, el problema es que al momento de hacer las transacciones con el pdo (que son varias) el php me muestra errores con referente a funciones que tienen los objetos pdo (como por ejemplo que lastInsertId() no esta declarada)... Ademas estoy poniendo en duda la la forma en como estoy creando la tabla 'propietarioDebeCuota'

aqui coloco el codigo php (estoy haciendolo con el patron MVC)

```
function registrarCuota($datos){
            try{
                $query = $this->db->connect();
                $query->beginTransaction();
                $query->prepare('INSERT INTO cuota(fechaC, monto) VALUES(:fecha, :monto)');
                $query->execute([':fecha'=>$datos['fecha'],':monto'=>$datos['monto']]);
                $idCuota = $query->lastInsertId();

                $query->query('SELECT idPropietario FROM propietario');

                while($row = $query->fetch()){
                    $propietario = "";
                    $propietario = $row['idPropietario'];
                    $query->prepare('INSERT INTO propietarioDebeCuota(idPropieraio, idCuotaDeudora) VALUES(:propietario, :cuota)');
                    $query->execute([':propietario'=>$propietario,':cuota'=>$idCuota]);
                }
                $query->commit();

                return true;
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                return false;
            }
}
```

El punto de la tabla 'propietarioDebeCuota' es almacenar todos los propietarios y que cada uno tenga la id de la cuota establecida en ese mes(la tabla cuota nunca tiene dos fecha iguales y las fechas solo contienen mes y año)

Comment: Supongo que la dificultad está en que la tabla de relación es 1 : N quieres evitar propietarios repetidos. Y que quieres insertar una cuota en particular que sea significativa, como la última pagada o la siguiente pendiente de pago. La definición de este campo es lo importante

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta y mostrar algunos registros de ejemplo y los que quieres obtener con tu consulta